# How does the memory of stack frame on call stack get freed when esp/ebp moves?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, memory

What I don't understand is, people say when the current stack frame is returned, meaning under the hood in assembly, the esp moves up, so the memory in the stack frame will be freed.

How exactly does this chunk of memory get freed after moving the esp pointer? by runtime or os by checking nothing points at them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free simply means that it's available for later use. Moving the stack pointer is sufficient to make everything past that point available for later use.

Comment: So does it mean that for the memory space, as long as there's no pointer points to the address, it is freed and shall be used?

Comment: It's not just that there's no pointer that points to it, it's that the stack pointer has been changed so that the space is made available for re-use. Just losing the pointers isn't enough because the implementation has tracking to know that it can't re-use that space -- that tracking must be adjusted. The stack pointer marks the boundary between used and free stack space.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the stack is a one time allocation that remains until a program terminates, regardless of the values in EBP or ESP.

Comment: if the program runs for long time, does that mean those memory won't be freed until then?

Comment: They are freed by moving the stack pointer. "Free" means that it doesn't contain anything useful and can be used for something else.

Comment: Yes, the allocated stack space remains allocated until the program terminates.

Comment: @rcgldr The OP seems to be asking about the stack  frame within a function. Not the stack allocated for an application...

Comment: Yeah, what tum_ said, it's not about returning unused pages *to the OS*, it's that `add esp, 32` makes those 32 bytes of space available for re-allocation by another `sub esp, 32`.